# Rails 2.2 doesn't want to redirect from https to http version of a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, https

I have a resource type called "Lesson".  For technical reasons (to do with the adobe Shockwave plugin), some older lessons are only playable on http pages, not https.

How I'm attempting to handle this is in the "show" action of the Lessons controller, as follows:  (`ldb` is a logging command)

```
def show
  #we can't play shockwave in https, so redirect to http if we're in https mode and the lesson has a shockwave resource
  if @lesson.needs_shockwave? && request.protocol == "https://"
    ldb "request.url = #{request.url}"
    new_url = request.url.gsub(/^https/,"http")
    ldb "redirecting to #{new_url}"
    redirect_to new_url and return
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.pdf { render :layout => false }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I can see in the logs that it generates the new http version of the url:

```
### request.url = https://local.charanga.com/lessons/134726?foo=bar
### redirecting to http://local.charanga.com/lessons/134726?foo=bar
```

However, the actual url that it redirects to still has https at the start, and so it gets stuck in a loop of constantly redirecting back to itself.  Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the http URL directly in your browser, does it stay on http, or redirect to https?

If it redirects, then it's worth checking:

1. Are you forcing SSL in your Rails app - maybe in `production.rb`?

   E.g. you'll have `config.force_ssl = true`.
   This will be forcing everything back to https.
2. Are you rewriting URLs at any level to use https by default e.g. in nginx, using rack-rewrite, as a CloudFlare rule etc. ?

Comment: Thanks.  In the browser it just stays on https and just looks like it's loading forever, until it gives up.  I'm not forcing https anywhere - I can go to the http version by manually editing the url in the address bar.

Comment: EDIT:  Actually I can't do the above:  I edit the browser bar to http but it still loads the https version!  So, it might be the browser's (Chrome) fault.  I'll try some other browsers.

Comment: Sorry, I think there is something (perhaps in my nginx config) which is forcing SSL after all.  I need to investigate further...

Comment: Ok, this is what happened.  In this git branch that I'm working in, which is to do with making the site work in https mode, one of my colleagues had (perhaps overzealously) added this line to one of the config files loaded by nginx:  `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=3600; includeSubDomains" always;`.  This has the effect of forcing https on the whole site, for at least an hour, after https has been used to access any page.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security

Comment: @MaxWilliams Glad you found the issue. Even after that's removed, you might find that Chrome remembers the redirect. You can force it to forget by going to the https page, opening up the dev console, and then right-click on the refresh button in the navbar and select "empty cache and hard reload". You might know this already, but thought I'd mention it - as it's saved me in the past!

Comment: This didn't work for me actually, and neither did deleting the cookies for my local site.  I had to change the rule to only force it for one second, instead of one hour, to get Chrome to stop forcing https!